# Is this the simplest form of this formula for a perimeter of a koch curve?

Tags: geometry

I had been thinking for a while of a formula to calculate the perimeter of a trianglar koch curve, and this is what I came up with:

$$\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{n+1}$$

Where n is the iteration you are on. Is this the simplest way for a formula like this?

Edit: I changed the fraction to $\frac{4}{3}$ as suggested
Edit edit: was wrong before, the formula has been fully simplified

Comment: You could write this as $(4/3)^{n+1}$ which is simpler?

Comment: The formula is wrong to me

Comment: @Med why? I checked it for the first four terms and it seemed correct?

Comment: I think, it sould be of form $4 \times (\frac{4}{3})^n$

Comment: Have you set the length of each side of the initial triangle as $1/3$?

Comment: If each side is $\frac{1}{3}$, then its fine.

Comment: @Med I'm starting off with a flat line of length 1 and the first iteration is where $n = 0$ which means that the length of the first Koch curve is $\frac{4}{3}$ which is true

Comment: @R.Duggan, you are right. I assumed a general length $a$ for the triangle and that's why I thought your formula is wrong.

Comment: In your edit, you seem to have misinterpreted @BenedictWilliamJohnIrwin's suggestion about the fraction. What you had originally ... $$\left(4^n\left(4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1}\right)\right)$$ can be transformed thusly $$4^n\cdot4\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1}= 4^{n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{3^{n+1}} = \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^{n+1}$$

Comment: @blue you're right, thanks for clearing that up